# CROSS APPLY OPENJSON / PIVOT - wrong ordering

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, azure-sql-database

the following code opens a json content and pivots it in the end. Somehow the ordering / pivoting mixes up wrongly.

```
WITH request
as
(
    SELECT requestId,
           property1191,
           '['+replace(replace(property1191, '[', ''), ']', '')+']' as json
    from capex_management_requests
)
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT
      P.requestId,
      AttsData.[Id],
      AttsData.[data],
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY P.requestId, AttsData.[Id]
                     ORDER BY (SELECT 1) ) AS row_id
    FROM request P
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (P.json, N'$') 
      WITH 
      (
        Id VARCHAR(200) N'$.metaId',
        data VARCHAR(200) N'$.data'
      ) AS AttsData
) DS
PIVOT 
(
     MAX(data) FOR Id IN ([690], [1192])
) piv;
```

**JSON example**

```
{"metaId":690,"data":"1"},{"metaId":1192,"data":"4352"}\],\[{"metaId":690,"data":"2"},{"metaId":1192,"data":"3887"}\],\[{"metaId":690,"data":"3"},{"metaId":1192,"data":"4372"}\],\[{"metaId":690,"data":"4"},{"metaId":1192,"data":"3749"}\],\[{"metaId":690,"data":"51"},{"metaId":1192,"data":"3693"}\],\[{"metaId":690,"data":"51"},{"metaId":1192,"data":"3712"}\],\[{"metaId":690,"data":"89"},{"metaId":1192,"data":"4228"}
```

**Current results - wrong ordering** (e.g. 690: 1 should show 1192: 4352)

| requestId | row_id | 690 | 1192 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 7 | 1 | 4228 |
| 1 | 6 | 2 | 3712 |
| 1 | 5 | 3 | 3693 |
| 1 | 4 | 4 | 3749 |
| 1 | 2 | 51 | 3887 |
| 1 | 3 | 51 | 4372 |
| 1 | 1 | 89 | 4352 |

**Target - correct ordering** (row_id not shown)

| requestId | row_id | 690 | 1192 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | x | 1 | 4352 |
| 1 | x | 2 | 3887 |
| 1 | x | 3 | 4372 |
| 1 | x | 4 | 3749 |
| 1 | x | 51 | 3693 |
| 1 | x | 51 | 3712 |
| 1 | x | 89 | 4228 |

I am interested in the correct ordering according to JSON syntax

Comment: Can you please run this query and report what it says: `SELECT @@version;` Given the syntax you show in your SQL example, I think you're using Microsoft SQL Server, even though you have tagged the question mysql.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8   Mar  8 2023 17:58:50   Copyright (C) 2022 Microsoft Corporation

Comment: I edited the tags. It's important to tag questions accurately, because it helps to attract the attention of people who are best able to answer your question.

Comment: Can you supply some usable sample data? Your query references multiple columns, however, the only data we have is your JSON.

Comment: The ordering in json is lost due to `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) `You could use two openjson..the first to keep the ordering in the array and the second to get the values ASAttsdata: `SELECT …  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY p.requestId, AttsData.[Id] ORDER BY cast(o.[key] as int)) AS row_id    FROM request P CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (P.json) as o CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(o.value) WITH ( Id …) AS AttsData…`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `JSON_VALUE` like the other answer, you can continue using `OPENJSON` with a schema. You just need two `OPENJSON` calls, once without a schema to get the array values with indexes, and once with a schema to break that out.

```sql
WITH request
as
(
    SELECT requestId,
           property1191,
           '['+replace(replace(property1191, '[', ''), ']', '')+']' as json
    from capex_management_requests
)
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT
      P.requestId,
      AttsData.[Id],
      AttsData.[data],
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY P.requestId, AttsData.[Id]
                     ORDER BY CAST(arr.[key] AS int)) AS row_id
    FROM request P
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (P.json) AS arr
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (arr.value)
      WITH 
      (
        Id VARCHAR(200) N'$.metaId',
        data VARCHAR(200)
      ) AS AttsData
) DS
PIVOT 
(
     MAX(data) FOR Id IN ([690], [1192])
) piv;
```

Comment: a follow up question to the code above. If there are multiple entries for  [1192] how should the code be adapted?

Comment: I don't know, because I don't know what result you want. Do you want `MAX` or `SUM` or something else?

Comment: I want to get all values of [1192] for each [690] - could be that there are multiple entries see target table => 690: 51 1192: 3693 & 3712

Comment: Then why are you pivoting? Just returrn it all in separate rows, with two columns `Id` and `data`, and leave out the row_number

Answer (score 1):

The sort is messed up cause you use (SELECT NULL).
To get proper ordering you need to use the "edge" version of OPENJSON, something like this:

```sql
declare @json nvarchar(max) = N'{"metaId":690,"data":"1"},{"metaId":1192,"data":"4352"}\],\[{"metaId":690,"data":"2"},{"metaId":1192,"data":"3887"}\],\[{"metaId":690,"data":"3"},{"metaId":1192,"data":"4372"}\],\[{"metaId":690,"data":"4"},{"metaId":1192,"data":"3749"}\],\[{"metaId":690,"data":"51"},{"metaId":1192,"data":"3693"}\],\[{"metaId":690,"data":"51"},{"metaId":1192,"data":"3712"}\],\[{"metaId":690,"data":"89"},{"metaId":1192,"data":"4228"}'
;WITH request
as
(
    SELECT 1 requestId,
           'test' property1191,
           '['+replace(replace(@json, '\[', ''), '\]', '')+']' as json
)
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT  P.requestId
    ,   JSON_VALUE(AttsData.value, '$.metaId') as id
    ,   JSON_VALUE(AttsData.value, '$.data') as data
    ,   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY P.requestId, JSON_VALUE(AttsData.value, '$.metaId') ORDER BY CAST(attsdata.[key] AS INT)) AS row_id
    FROM request P
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (P.json)  AttsData
) DS
PIVOT 
(
     MAX(data) FOR Id IN ([690], [1192])
) piv;
```

Comment: You don't need `JSON_VALUE` you can just `CROSS APPLY OPENJSON` again

Comment: Too much typing in my opinion :)

Comment: Damn, i even got removed as accepted :D Is double openjson really better than json_value? Am i missing something? I thought the performance of multi-jsons would be worse

Comment: Depends how many you do in my experience. 1, maybe 2, calls to `JSON_VALUE` is OK, but beyond that it's faster to do `OPENJSON`. Don't beat yourself up, it was a good answer anyway.