# Cross apply openjson / pivot - multiple entries

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, azure-sql-database

The following code, written by [Charlieface](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14868997/charlieface) in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75921428/2029983), converts and opens a json content and pivots it in the end. It could be the case that multpiple entries can occur. How does the code need to be adapted to cover that as well?

> ```
> WITH request
> as
> (
>     SELECT requestId,
>            property1191,
>            '['+replace(replace(property1191, '[', ''), ']', '')+']' as json
>     from capex_management_requests
> )
> SELECT *
> FROM
> (
>     SELECT
>       P.requestId,
>       AttsData.[Id],
>       AttsData.[data],
>       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY P.requestId, AttsData.[Id]
>                      ORDER BY CAST(arr.[key] AS int)) AS row_id
>     FROM request P
>     CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (P.json) AS arr
>     CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (arr.value)
>       WITH 
>       (
>         Id VARCHAR(200) N'$.metaId',
>         data VARCHAR(200)
>       ) AS AttsData
> ) DS
> PIVOT 
> (
>      MAX(data) FOR Id IN ([690], [1192])
> ) piv;
> ```

**Current outcome - only "MAX" value for each ID [690] value**

| requestId | row_id | 690 | 1192 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | x | 1 | 4352 |
| 1 | x | 2 | 3887 |
| 1 | x | 3 | 4372 |
| 1 | x | 4 | 3749 |
| 1 | x | 51 | 3693 |
| 1 | x | 89 | 4228 |

**Target - multiple entries instead of "MAX" for each ID [690] value**

| requestId | row_id | 690 | 1192 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | x | 1 | 4100 |
| 1 | x | 1 | 4352 |
| 1 | x | 2 | 3887 |
| 1 | x | 3 | 4200 |
| 1 | x | 3 | 4300 |
| 1 | x | 3 | 4372 |
| 1 | x | 4 | 3749 |
| 1 | x | 51 | 3693 |
| 1 | x | 51 | 3712 |
| 1 | x | 89 | 4228 |

I want to be able to also cover multiple entries correctly!

Comment: Check your title, ALL CAPS is considered SHOUTING at us.

Comment: Are you sure anything is removed? row_id should ensure unique values, unless you don't include it in your pivot query

Comment: The original answer to this question didn't exhibit this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75920520/cross-apply-openjson-pivot-wrong-ordering/75921050#75921050

Comment: without pivoting in the end the multiple entries are as well not there so I guess the issue results out of the upper section

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question, I believe you would avoid the `PIVOT` to avoid the MAX aggregation. You can use `CASE` statements to pick out the values that the pivot would have. I put the subquery as another CTE to perhaps make it clearer what's going on.

```sql
WITH request
as
(
    SELECT requestId,
           property1191,
           '['+replace(replace(property1191, '[', ''), ']', '')+']' as json
    from capex_management_requests
), 
ds AS (
    SELECT
      P.requestId,
      AttsData.[Id],
      AttsData.[data],
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY P.requestId, AttsData.[Id]
                     ORDER BY CAST(arr.[key] AS int)) AS row_id
    FROM request P
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (P.json) AS arr
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (arr.value)
      WITH 
      (
        Id VARCHAR(200) N'$.metaId',
        data VARCHAR(200)
      ) AS AttsData
)
SELECT 
    requestId, 
    data,
    row_id,
    CASE WHEN Id = '690' THEN data ELSE NULL END AS [690],
    CASE WHEN Id = '1192' THEN data ELSE NULL END AS [1192]
FROM ds
```

Comment: results in error => Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 31
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.

Comment: Oops. Left a dangling comma. Updating